# In Python, how is `datetime.datetime.now()` an "unaware" datetime object?

Tags: python, python-datetime

Apparently, I must run `pytz.UTC.localize(datetime.datetime.now())` before I compare the current time with other "naive" time objects.

Why is that? Isn't the current time relevant to specific time zones?

Comment: The discussion on http://bugs.python.org/issue9527 may be relevant? (Also http://bugs.python.org/issue12756 , applying to `utcnow()`, closed as won't fix because being tz-aware might break backwards compatibility)

Comment: Ah thanks! That explains it I think.

Comment: How do you get the current time? datetime.datetime.now()?

Comment: Yes, I used `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().utcoffset() is None
True
```

The `now` function does indeed return a naive object.  It contains field values for day and time that are populated according to locale settings.  That is why a separate `utcnow` is provided; that always gives you UTC field values (though it is still naive).